# How can I determine if a browser is configured to view a PDF externally using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

My application is showing a PDF in a new tab whenever a PDF link is clicked. This works fine except for when a user has their browser configured to automatically view a PDF externally using Acrobat (or any another program). In this scenario, a blank tab opens when they click the PDF link which then leads to an external application handling the PDF. Ultimately, when the user returns to the browser, they're staring at a blank tab. I'd like to find some javascript that can do the following:

```
var externalApplicationEnabled = someMagicalJavascriptLogic(); //returns true or false

if(externalApplicationEnabled === true){
    //view file in current tab (or alternatively just download the file)
}
else{
    //view file in new tab
}
```

I'm looking for the magic that happens within someMagicalJavascriptLogic();

Comment: My opinion (which you did not ask for) is to let the user deal with his personal environment as he wishes.  If he has configured his machine to open PDFs in an external application, he should be used to blank tabs and will know how to handle them.

Comment: @SteveH. You and I are of the same opinion.. But my boss thinks differently which is why I am trying to solve this. Thanks though, appreciated.

Comment: Tell your boss to read about the "Principle of Least Astonishment". You got me curious and I did find this plugin detector: http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/All/